# Error: Cannot find any non-recursive equality over Q0 in Coq

Tags: error-handling, coq

Theorem preservation : forall Pi e T1 S e' Q S', hasType empty Pi e T1 -> storeWellTyped Pi S -> step (conf (e :: Q) S) (conf (e' :: Q) S') -> exists Pi', (extends Pi' Pi /\ hasType empty Pi' e' T1 /\ storeWellTyped Pi' S'). – Amit 3 mins ago   edit

When I am trying to prove this theorem e get replaced by various expressions in my syntax but e' does not get replaced by corresponding stepped expression. For example if e is e1;e2 then e' should be e1';e2 in the hypothesis. But e' does not changes so it becomes difficult to prove.

I was trying to do induction on the hypothesis hasType empty Pi e T1 and got the various cases for each expression to prove but due to above problem I could not proceed further.

Error: Cannot find any non-recursive equality over Q0.

I was trying to prove preservation theorem where I got this error. I don't really understand what it means and how it can be eliminated. This error pops out after using subst with inversion.

Comment: What is `Q0`? To be able to help you we'd need some code we could "run". Please see this help page on [MCVE].

Comment: Q0 represents queue in the configuration of the program which takes step from one configuration to another.

Comment: Theorem preservation : forall Pi e T1 S e' Q S',
hasType empty Pi e T1 ->
storeWellTyped Pi S ->
step (conf (e :: Q) S) (conf (e' :: Q) S') ->
exists Pi', (extends Pi' Pi /\
hasType empty Pi' e' T1 /\
storeWellTyped Pi' S').

Comment: When I am trying to prove this theorem e get replaced by various expressions in my syntax but e' does not get replaced by corresponding stepped expression. For example if e is e1;e2 then e' should be e1';e2 in the hypothesis. But e' does not changes so it becomes difficult to ptove

Comment: You should include all the new information in your post, comments are not very reliable on stackoverflow and it's easier to read a consistent post, than a collection of comments.

Comment: There is little can be done without your proof script. However, I'll try to make a wild guess. If you have a hypothesis with equality, like this `Q0 : x = 1` and a goal, let's say `x = 1`, then `subst Q0.` will give you the exact same error message. Instead you should say `subst x.`, then Coq will find the equation for `x` in the context. You can try `rewrite Q0.`, `subst x.`, or just `subst.`.

Comment: In my above theorem, I started my proof as Proof with eauto using store_weakening, extends_refl.
remember (@empty type) as Gamma.
intros Pi e T1 S e' Q S' H1 H2.
generalize dependent e'.
induction H1; intros e' Hstep;
    subst; try (solve by inversion); inversion Hstep; subst ;
    try (eauto using store_weakening, extends_refl). After this above proof step I get the error "Cannot find any non-recursive equality over Q0."

Comment: That looks like an exercise from Software Foundations. If this is the case the reference to the exercise would be helpful.